# ExpressJS setup for CORS and session with preflight calls

Tags: express, session, cors

I'm trying to set up a server, which is handling 3rd party requests, IE the domain it's coming from is our client's, but I need to proxy requests to our API through this Express application.  I need to store some information in a session, for which I'm using a Redis Cache to store the actual data.

I've been running in a series of CORS problems while attempting to do this.  So far, this is the configuration I've got.  It works find on my local development machine simulating both servers on different ports, but when I deploy, I get a `CORS No Allow Credentials` error on Preflight OPTION, and a `NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI` on the subsequent POST.

I've basically hit a stone wall in figuring this out.  I thought it was the origin, but I have defined an origin whitelist and that didn't help.

Any help for my configuration would be appreciated

```js
    // set session cookie options, all environments
    const cookieOptions = {
      maxAge:   24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,  // 24 hours
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: 'none',   // sameSite and secure are necessary
      secure:   true      // to set 3rd party cookie for session
    }

    // express session configuration options
    const sessionOptions = {
      store:  new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
      secret: process.env.sessionKey,
      cookie: cookieOptions,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
    }

    app.set('trust proxy', 2)

    app.use( cors({
        origin:      validateCorsOrigins,  // also had the same error with this set to true
        methods:     'GET, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS',   // OPTIONS is necessary for preflight
        credentials: true     // client will have to set credentials as well
      })
    )

    app.use( session( sessionOptions ) )


    // POST endpoint
    app.post('/api/cars', (req, res, next) => {
      const session = req.session

      ....do some processing....
      session.vin = vin

      res.json({ cars: cars })
    })
```

I have to use the `trust proxy` setting because I am deploying into a Docker container.

Client Code

```js
  var headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' });
  
  var payload = { <payload body here/> };
  
  var request = new Request(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
      mode: 'cors',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: headers
  });
  const response = await fetch(request);
  const json = await response.json().catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
  });
  ...
```

Preflight Request Headers OPTION call

```
OPTIONS /api/cars HTTP/2
Host: proxyhost.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Firefox/90.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Referer: https://localhost:5000/
Origin: https://localhost:5000
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Preflight Response Headers

```
HTTP/2 200 OK
server: Kestrel
access-control-allow-headers: content-type
access-control-allow-origin: *
date: Sun, 20 Jun 2021 17:05:27 GMT
content-length: 0
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

POST

`Referrer Policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin`

POST Request Headers

```
POST /api/cars undefined
Host: proxyhost.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0  
Firefox/90.0
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://localhost:5000/
content-type: application/json
Origin: https://localhost:5000
Content-Length: 44
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: <cookie stuff/>
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question turned out to be a problem with Azure AppServices overriding the CORS settings of my Application.  AppServices CORS settings will take precedence if they are defined.  You must disable CORS on the AppService to allow the CORS settings on the Node Application to work.

```
$ az webapp cors remove --allowed-origins --resource-group "<resource_group_name>" --name "<app_service_name>" --slot "<slot_name>"
```

The results should be:

```
{
  "allowedOrigins": [],
  "supportCredentials": false
}
```